# Sybase Data transfer utility

Tags: replication, sybase, utility

I am looking for a Sybase utility that would update any data change in one table in a sybase main server to archive server.

I remember i used it once when I used to work in a different firm but I don't remember the name.

When I was in previous firm, when there was an issue with replciation server. I used that utility to manually sync main server to remote readyonly archive server. I don't think it was entire databas syce. It was more of synce of one table at a time.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `Warm Standby`.

You can do this only via Sybase Replication Server

check [official docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc32518_1500/html/rsadmin_vol_2/BABHJGJI.htm).

but in real world - Warm Standby is not stable B)

Also u can syncing via bcp copy or dump and restor via NFS.